# __init__.py correct import layout?

Tags: python, package, pypi

File Structure:

```
device
   device.py
   __init__.py
```

`__init__.py` contains just one line:

```
from device import *
```

device.py just has a bunch of functions, and I want to include all of them with
`from device import *`, except I have to use `from device.device import *` after pip installing.

How can I get rid of the extra scope so it's just `from device import *`?

Comment: `from . import *` =D

Comment: @sashaaero That didn't work for me.

Comment: from dataglove.dataglove import *       - this worked in the --init--.py

Comment: however, i noticed it works on python 3.6 but not 2.7

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `__all__ = ['one_function_name', 'another_one']` with `one_function_name` and `another_one` imported previously in your `__init__.py`.

The `from <package> import *` is not a good idea because you will import package that you import in file (the `__all__` variable protect against this, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44842/11832127)) but it is not a good practice.

edit:
sashaaero comment does want you want.

Comment: Seems too extensive, since I have a lot of functions.

Answer (score 0):

Either:

- move the functions from `device.py` to `__init__.py`, or
- use `from .device import *` in `__init__.py`.

Comment: Hmm, can I get your input on something then. Basically, I'm just making a wrapper so the API functions are handled in one file right now. Does that make device.py sorta extraneous then. I tried the 2nd option and that didn't work.